# Add buttons on google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to add some stylish button on Google map in my application just the placed in image.

Kindly help me to add.Thanks in Advance.

Here is the demo that i want to create

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete and verifiable code, if you have any error post your error logs. Here's a related SO ticket: [SO 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694119/how-to-add-buttons-at-top-of-map-fragment-api-v2-layout), [SO 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136299/how-to-add-custom-controls-to-mapfragment-in-google-maps-android-api-v2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a view that decorates/wraps your Google Map View. You can then configure this view how you would like with buttons, overlays, etc and use click listeners to delegate to the map events you would like performed.